# How to join 1:N tables in rails and instead of multiple rows for record get one row with extra column containing array of IDs from joined table

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have 3 models

```
class Mission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guild
end

class Guild < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :missions
    has_many :guild_coordinators, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :coordinators, :through=> :guild_coordinators, :class_name => "Associate"
end

class GuildCoordinator < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guild
  belongs_to :coordinator, :class_name => "Associate"
end
```

If I do

> Mission.joins(:guild => :guild_coordinators)

I get row for every guild -> guild coordinator association

Is it possible to get unique records for Missions with joined Guilds and in one column get IDs of all coordinators in an Array?

edit:
expected result is something like this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Mission id: 13, fy: 2018, guild_id: 31, name: "test mission", status: 0, coordinators: [1,2,3,5,8]>
```

my database is postgres
as output I need Active Record relation for gem ajax-datatables-rails

Comment: You can do `missions = Mission.includes(guild: :guild_coordinators).to_a` and then `missions.first.guild.guild_coordinators` is an array of GuildCoordinator for unique first Mission. If you'd like array of IDs for someth., you have to specify 1) what exact result do you need, 2) your DB, because query will be DB specific.

Comment: I have added these info to the question, thx

Comment: What if you add `has_many :guild_coordinators, through: :guild` to your missions model and then get a relation like `Mission.includes(:guild_coordinators)`? Will that give you what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Postgresql you can use [`array_agg` aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
Mission.
  joins(guild: :guild_coordinators).
  select('missions.*, array_agg(guild_coordinators.id) as coordinators').
  group(:id)
```

And you get exactly `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which will contain(after call) `Mission` objects with additional field `coordinators`:Array.

The second option is to use `.includes` like my or @garrett-motzner comments show.